# Convert a string of comma separated values into a JSON array

Tags: php, jquery, json

How can I convert a string of comma separated values into valid json, using either php or jquery?

The comma separated strings are stored in a database and are like this:

`Singapore,Andora,Australia`

The output I need is like this: `["Singapore","Andora","Australia"]`

I tried using php's `json_encode` on the string, but that does not render json the way I need it. It does this `"Singapore,Andora,Australia"`

Any way I could get this the way I want it?

Comment: `"Singapore,Andora,Australia".split(',')` will return you an array of strings

Answer (score 8):

Split the string and then encode the array:

```
$str = "Singapore,Andora,Australia";
$splitted = explode(",", $str);
print_r(json_encode($splitted));
// output : ["Singapore","Andora","Australia"]
```

[Example in sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2501b444891b4468a44a5b86ac9b87c323bb200a).

Answer (score 1):

`explode` ([Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)) the string (to make it an array) and then convert it to json with the `json_encode` function.

Answer (score 1):

Did you `explode()` the PHP string before encoding it?

```
json_encode(explode(',', $string));
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution in PHP:

```
$raw = "Singapore,Andora,Australia";
// Use explode() to parse the string into an array
$parsed = explode(",",  $raw);
// Encode the resulting array as JSON
$encoded = json_encode($parsed);
```

Solution in JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var encoded = JSON.stringify("Singapore,Andora,Australia".split(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery :
For Array,

```
var array = myString.split(',');
```

For String,

```
var string = JSON.stringify(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as:

```
var data = "Singapore,Andora,Australia".split(",");
console.log(data); //["Singapore", "Andora", "Australia"]
```

thats is gonna return an array with three values